# I am trying to track the moving ants in the video in opencv. I am not able to track the ants. suggestions? Code and link is provided

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

This is the video link:I am trying to track the moving ants in the provided video link. Unfortunately, i am not able to do so. suggestions?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bc_OdLgGrPQ&feature=youtu.be%22

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import imutils

black_lower = (0,0,0) #this two-blacks corresponds to the colour range in hsv, which we are looking in ants
black_upper = (130, 130, 138)
kernel_erode = np.ones((1.0,1.0),np.uint8)
#these kernels are defined for eroding and dialating image
#kernel_dialate = np.ones((1,1),np.uint8)
#r,h,c,w = 600, 400, 100, 700 # i have to play with the size of the window for getting the roi (currently cutting defined roi)
#track_window = (c,r,w,h)
vid = cv2.VideoCapture('/home/marcusidaho/Desktop/opencv_files/tandem_run_classic.mp4')
while (vid.isOpened()):
ret,frame = vid.read()
frame = imutils.resize(frame,width=600) #we have resized the frame, now we have to convert to hsv color space!
ret1,thresh = cv2.threshold(frame,100,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(thresh,cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)# we have converted the frame in to hsv space!
cv2.imshow('thresh',thresh)
cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_frame,black_lower,black_upper)#now we sh*ould define a mask for color ranges from black_lower to black_upper and remove other noices!
mask = cv2.erode(mask,kernel_erode,iterations=1)#for increasing the object detection , we have to reduce the erode_kernel_size and increase the dialate_kernel_size
mask = cv2.Canny(mask, 150, 255)
mask = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame,mask=mask)#for extracting specific region of the image
mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
mask3 = cv2.dilate(mask2,kernel_dialate,iterations=2)
mask4 = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask3,(1,1),0)
x,y,w,h = track_window # these are for defining the roi in the video, will have to play with this!
cv2.rectangle(mask4,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
dst = np.zeros_like(mask4)
dst[y:y+h,x:x+w] = mask4[y:y+h,x:x+w]
cv2.imshow('gray',frame)
#this is finding the specific object in the video and drawing a contour against it
counts = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2] #findcountour saves the x and y coordinates of the boundary
#print counts
center = None
if len(counts) > 0:
    calculate = max(counts,key = cv2.contourArea)
    #print calculate
    ((x,y),radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(calculate)
    print(radius)
    M = cv2.moments(calculate) #used to calculate the center of mass of the object
    center = (int(M['m10']/M['m00']),int(M['m01']/M['m00'])) #used to extract the centroid
    if radius > 6 :
        cv2.circle(frame, (int(x),int(y)),int(radius),(0,255,255),2)
        cv2.circle(frame, center, 5 ,(0,0,255),-1)
        pts = np.append(center,(int(x),int(y)))

for i in xrange(1,len(pts)):
    if pts[i-1] is None or pts[i] is None:
        continue
        thickness = int(np.sqrt(64/float(i+1))*2.5)
cv2.line(frame,pts[i-1],pts[i],(0,0,255),thickness)
cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
if cv2.waitKey(50) and 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
vid.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like static background so I would:

1. **on Each frame `A`**

   blur `A` a bit to remove noise
2. **substract/threshold last frame `A0` from `A`**

   so `dA=A-A0` and create **ROI** by `|dA|>threshold`. This mask will contain areas where ants where and are now.
3. **set last frame**

   so `A0=A`

To  recognize which part of **ROI** is the old and actual ant position just check correspondent pixel in `A` for black ...

I do not use **Python** nor **OpenCV** so I am not confident to provide any code ...

Instead of `A0` you can also use the background image (without ants) or integrated/averaged image over time...

Comment: thank you for your answer. Can you tell me how to move across frames for image substraction ? I have converted the video in to frames, now i am not able to access the video frames from the folder.

Comment: @marcosidaho when you process your video or grab frames from camera then you should got 1 frame at your disposal (does not matter if in for loop or in some event handler) so you just copy actual frame to some temp image after processing is done. This way on next frame you got the last frame in that temp and can use it.... of coarse for the first frame there is no previous frame so you skip processing for it. If you are generating image files for each frame on disk and do not close them then they are open for write which is usually exlusive access and until closed you can not use them  so fixit